# Canadian Citizen, but can I leave Canada with a foreign passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens, austrian-citizens

I am Canadian citizen with an Austrian passport as well. I wish to leave Pearson Airport using only my Austrian passport to live in EU. (I am in Canada a Canadian) Would this be acceptable?

Comment: Canada does not check your passport on departure.

Comment: I would say it's actually very much recommended. If you plan to enter Austria (or the EU as a EU citizen), you are supposed to use your Austrian (EU) passport, not a foreign one. Hence, you should use the Austrian passport for your flight in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

The government of Canada won't check your passport upon departure, so this is not a problem.

Your airline will check your passport, but they just want you to hold a valid passport; they won't care what country it's from.

You will, of course, want to have your Canadian passport with you for your return to Canada.

Comment: The airline may not care (that much) what country your passport is from, but they do care a lot if you are allowed to enter your destination country (depending on the country they will check if you require/hold a valid visa) and may not let you board without it.

Comment: ^ is seconded from personal experience.  I'm dual Canada/Hong Kong citizen and when I showed them my Canadian Passport at departure, the airline almost didn't let me on until I mentioned I have a Hong Kong resident card.  They have to register either a valid Visa or a valid citizenship documentation for the destination.

Answer (score 3):

I have dual citizenship in the U.S. & Canada, and I live in the U.S.  Since I have relatives on both sides of the border, I have flown and driven across the border more times than I can count, presenting my U.S. passport when entering the United States and my Canadian passport when I have entered Canada.  I have never once run into a problem with this.  Since Canada does not have exit controls, I doubt that replacing "US" with "Austria" above will yield any problems.

Entering Canada, I always present my Canadian passport.  This means that there's usually a part of the conversation with the border guard that goes like this:

> *Canadian border guard:*  Where do you live?
>
> *Me:*  Connecticut.
>
> *CBG:*  What's your legal status in the US?
>
> *Me:*  I'm a dual citizen.  Do you need to see my U.S. Passport?
>
> *CBG:*  No.

This is the sum total of the explanations I've ever had to give about having multiple citizenships and passports.  (But then, I'm a upper-middle-class white male;  YMMV if you're from a group that gets treated with more suspicion.)